# How to track a hover over action?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, hover

We are using a very simple CSS to create a flyout window:

```
<style type="text/css">
#flyout_window {
    position:absolute;
    top:85px;
    left:10px;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    margin-left: -450px;
    }                      
    #flyout_window:hover{margin-left: 0px;}
</style>
```

You can see what it looks like here: http://xeeme.com/axels 
It works just fine and is heavily used. Now, since this resides on the client, how can we track how often the flyout was used and record usage on the server?

Some Ajax maybe? Any suggestion what worked for you in such a situation?
We are using Coldfusion9

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is not Javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the action is occurring on the browser-side, but you want to keep a record of it on the server-side, you must tell the browser to fire a certain page on your server when the user hovers over your target area.

So Ajax is the most sensible solution here.

As for the page that's going to track the events on your server, you can either build your own tracking system or use external analytics platforms such as Mixpanel (http://mixpanel.com).

By the way, the code you've posted is CSS, not JavaScript.

Comment: Of course CSS - my bad (just edited it). Do you have an ajax snippet? How would I implement it? I can deal with it on the server side but have some trouble of finding a starting point on the client side.

With a button, I'd use: onClick="return something('some ID');"...
But all I have is a DIV with an ID
<div id="flyout_window" class="Text1" style="position:absolute; width:440px;height:325px;#helpStyle#; z-index:99;">

Comment: OK, I'll try this: <div id="flyout" class="text1" onmouseover="return('some id')"> ...